# Installing SystemC 2.2.0, compilation with GCC 4.6 and package for Fedora

Tags: fedora, clang, gcc4, systemc

How to install SystemC on Fedora 15?

Problems:

- no RPM package (licensing problems)
- does not compile with 4.6
- even with -fpermissive (clang doesn't compile your modules)

Comment: The OSCI SystemC installation is such a kludge and setup for (now) old versions of Gcc.  It would be nice if OSCI would update their SystemC installation instructions, scripts and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is extremely useful and well writen [blog post](http://chitlesh.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/installing-systemc-on-fedora/) by Chitlesh Goorah, please read it first.

Then what reminds is how to compile SystemC library with GCC 4.6. You can add -fpermissive, but I **strongly advice against it**.

Instead there are 4 lines of code that needs to be changed, here is the patch:

```
--- src/sysc/datatypes/bit/sc_bit_proxies.h 2007-03-14 17:47:49.000000000 +0000
+++ src/sysc/datatypes/bit/sc_bit_proxies.h.mod 2011-09-02 13:53:34.318379140 +0000
@@ -713,7 +713,7 @@

 protected:

-    mutable X& m_obj;
+    X&         m_obj;
     int        m_hi;
     int        m_lo;
     int        m_len;
@@ -1190,10 +1190,10 @@

 protected:

-    mutable X&   m_left;
-    mutable Y&   m_right;
+            X&   m_left;
+            Y&   m_right;
     mutable int  m_delete;
-    mutable int& m_refs;
+            int& m_refs;
```

As a bonus, changes above make this header to work with Clang (tested with 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, you also need to patch `sc_utils_ids.cpp` to add missing headers.

```
--- src/sysc/utils/sc_utils_ids.cpp     2006-12-15 20:31:39.000000000 +0000
+++ src/sysc/utils/sc_utils_ids.cpp.mod 2011-11-02 15:49:10.431948273 +0000
@@ -59,6 +59,9 @@
 //

 #include "sysc/utils/sc_report.h"
+// Jeremy Bennett 2 Nov 11. Patched for GCC 4.6.
+#include <cstdlib>
+#include <cstring>


 namespace sc_core {
```